"Entails" in probability propositions: Why are these claims made by the author true?
I've just began reading "Probability: A Philosophical Introduction" by D.H. Mellor. In chapter 1, section 8, he states:

... the epistemic probability of a proposition conditional on evidence which entails it is 1; and this rule applies to all numerical probabilities, not just epistemic ones. In symbols, if '←' means 'entails', then for all propositions A and B:
(1.7) If A ← B, then if P(B) = 1, P(A) = 1
This follows from the more basic rule that
(1.8) No proposition is more probable than any proposition it entails, i.e.
If A ← B, then P(A) ≤ P(B)
(It cannot, for example, be more probable that Pink Gin will win the Derby by finishing first than that Pink gin will at least finish.)

But here I think I'm misunderstanding what is meant by entails [maybe]. It makes sense that the (epistemic) probability of a position conditioned on evidence which entails it is 1—but from that it doesn't seem to follow that P(B) cannot be greater than P(A).
What if, for example, B occurs if A occurs or if C occurs, while A and C can occur independently of one another. In that case, A ← B, and if P(B) = 1 it could be that P(A) = 0 and P(C) = 1, or, ultimately, that P(A) ∨ P(C) = 1.
Am I misunderstanding what is meant by entails? It seems all-in-all similar to implies (if A entails B and A is true, then, by necessity, B is true).

There is something wrong with that quote. I don't know if A ← B means that A entails B or B entails A. If it's B entails A then (1.7) is true, but if it's A entails B then (1.8) is true. They can't both be true.

@DavidGudeman Ok. In that case my guess is there's just a typo. in the book?

It is only a weird use of the symbol. "Entails" must be read as usual: B entails A means that A follows from B, i.e. that every time B is true, also A is. Thus, if P(B)=1, we have that B is always true.

Are you sure that the symbol for entails isn't a turnstile ⊢ rather than an arrow? That is a commonly used symbol for entailment. A entails B is equivalent to saying that B is the logical consequence of A.

@Bumble The text that I have uses \leftarrow, but I wouldn't be surprised if there's been some weird encoding error. Anyway I'm now comfortable that there's some error somewhere and it's not just me missing something
